# Iterating inside an IF statement conditioned by a list in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, if-statement, list-comprehension

Suppose I have a df:

```
     Name    Surname  Age
0    Alex    Jackson   10
1     Bob      Black   12
2  Clarke  Flingston   13
3  Claude      White   11
4   Julia     Waters   10
5  Robert    Ferrari   12
6    Anna        Red    9
7   David       Blue   10
8    Luke        Man   12
```

and with:

```
list_n = []
for age, surname in zip(df.Age, df.Surname):
    if (age != 13 and 
        age != 11 and 
        age != 10):
        list_n.append(surname)

list_n
['Black', 'Ferrari', 'Red', 'Man']
```

I get a list of surnames excluding the ones with a certain age. **Is it possible to iterate the if condition with a list of ages?**

I tried with list comprehension but it does not work as it should be:

```
list_age = [13,11,10]
list_n = []

for age, surname in zip(df.Age, df.Surname):
    [list_n.append(surname) for x in list_Age if age != x]

list_n
['Jackson', 'Jackson',  'Black',  'Black',  'Black', 'Flingston',
 'Flingston',  'White',  'White',  'Waters',  'Waters',  'Ferrari',
 'Ferrari',  'Ferrari',  'Red',  'Red',  'Red',  'Blue',  'Blue',
 'Man',  'Man',   'Man']
```

Comment: I feel like you could do `df[~df.Age.isin(list_age)]` to get the rows where Age is not equal to any of the ages in `list_age`. Not to sound like a Ahole but there is a saying that if you are using for loops with pandas objects, you're likely doing something wrong

Comment: Why not replace the ```age != 13 and ....``` for ` age not in list_age`?

Comment: Yes @Jano I actually forgot about the "not in"..

Comment: In any case, best option is the one offered by @Buckeye14Guy. ```df[~df.Age.isin(list_age)]['Surname']``` Adding a .tolist() if you want it to be a list specifically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also achieve the end result directly using *masking techniques* of pandas dataframe,

Try this,

```
list_n = df["Surname"][~df["Age"].isin(list_age)].to_list()
```

and when you executes `>>>print(list_n)`

**Output:**

```
['Black', 'Ferrari', 'Red', 'Man']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list_n = [surname for age, surname in zip(df.Age, df.Surname)
          if age not in {10, 11, 13}]
```

Answer (score 1):

`list_n = [surname for age, surname in zip(df.Age, df.Surname) if age not in list_age]`